# Split time-series dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe where I have different parameters as columns and a timestamp for each row of parameters.

What I want to do is to split the dataframe into windows, where column values from each row get all appended into a single row. This will enable me to run clustering using these as features.

For example, I want to transform dataframe like this (window size 3):

```
2017-01-01 00:00:01, a1, b1, c1
2017-01-01 00:00:02, a2, b2, c2
2017-01-01 00:00:03, a3, b3, c3
2017-01-01 00:00:04, a4, b4, c4
2017-01-01 00:00:05, a5, b5, c5
2017-01-01 00:00:06, a6, b6, c6
2017-01-01 00:00:07, a7, b7, c7
```

Into something like this:

```
2017-01-01 00:00:01, 2017-01-01 00:00:03, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3
2017-01-01 00:00:04, 2017-01-01 00:00:06, a4, a5, a6, b4, b5, b6, c4, c5, c6
```

I need to preserve information which time interval belongs to which cluster, after clustering, so that is why I also need to keep the time ranges. The last instant in the example was excluded as there's not enough measurements to create another window.

How can I do this using Spark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with some data, according to your description:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp

df = sc.parallelize([("2017-01-01 00:00:01", 2.0, 2.0, 2.0),
("2017-01-01 00:00:08", 9.0, 9.0, 9.0),
("2017-01-01 00:00:02", 3.0, 3.0, 3.0),
("2017-01-01 00:00:03", 4.0, 4.0, 4.0),
("2017-01-01 00:00:04", 5.0, 5.0, 5.0),
("2017-01-01 00:00:05", 6.0, 6.0, 6.0),
("2017-01-01 00:00:06", 7.0, 7.0, 7.0),
("2017-01-01 00:00:07", 8.0, 8.0, 8.0)]).toDF(["time","a","b","c"])
df = df.withColumn("time", unix_timestamp("time", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp"))
```

**> Spark 2.0**

We could generate a new `interval` column using the `ceil()` function , by which then we can group your data and collect all the other variables into one flat list.

To guarantee correct ordering inside the resulting lists, irrespective of initial order, we'll use `Window` functions, to partition your data by `date`, creating a `rank` column ordered by the `time`.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import ceil

df = df.withColumn("date", df["time"].cast("date")) \
       .withColumn("interval", ((ceil(df["time"].cast("long") / 3L))*3.0).cast("timestamp")) 

window = Window.partitionBy(df['date']).orderBy(df['time'])
```

Because we'll collect the `rank` column into the nested list for correct ordering, we'll define an `udf` that eventually unpacks all values in the nested lists, but *the first one*, which is the `rank` :

```
def unnest(col):

  l = [item[1:] for item in col]
  res = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

  return(res)

unnest_udf = udf(unnest)
```

Now we putting everything together:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, array

df.select('*', rank().over(window).alias('rank')) \
  .groupBy("interval") \
  .agg(collect_list(array("rank","a", "b","c")).alias("vals")) \
  .withColumn("vals", unnest_udf("vals")) \
  .sort("interval") \
  .show(truncate = False)
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|interval             |vals                                         |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|2017-01-01 00:00:03.0|[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0]|
|2017-01-01 00:00:06.0|[5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0]|
|2017-01-01 00:00:09.0|[8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0]               |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

**Spark 1.6**

We cannot use `array` as an argument inside `collect_list()`, so we'll just wrap the `collect_list()` calls inside `array`, instead of the other way around. We'll also slightly modify our `udf` because we won't be explicitly needing the `rank` column using this approach.

```
unpack_udf = udf(
    lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
)

df.select('*', rank().over(window).alias('rank')) \
  .groupBy("interval") \
  .agg(array(collect_list("a"),
             collect_list("b"),
             collect_list("c")).alias("vals")) \
  .withColumn("vals", unpack_udf("vals")) \
  .sort("interval") \
  .show(truncate = False)
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|interval             |vals                                         |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|2017-01-01 00:00:03.0|[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]|
|2017-01-01 00:00:06.0|[5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]|
|2017-01-01 00:00:09.0|[8.0, 9.0, 8.0, 9.0, 8.0, 9.0]               |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Note that `vals` column is now ordered in a different way, yet consistently thanks to the `window` function we defined earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems good, I will test it. One thing bothers me, is it possible to get features out of order in this way, since I'm not sorting the data previously? For example, could first row be [a2, b1, c3, a1, b2, c2, a3, b3, c1], while second one [b4, a4, c4, a5, c5, b5, a6, b6, c6], or something like that? The order of features is very important, as I'll be running clustering afterwards?

Comment: Check the result without unpack_udf, the result will always be tuples in order of the columns, unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: I will do that, but, I'm not that afraid about the ordering of columns, but the order of original rows, if you know what I mean? Since data is not sorted by time and we group it by, for example, hour of the day (window size 60 instead of 3), how can I be sure that resulting rows will have same order of columns, that is, that rows considered are adjacent? What prevents row with a4 to come between rows a1 and a3, instead of a2?

Comment: Maybe I should calculate intervals, partition in some way (let's say by day, to have bigger partitions), sort partitions by timestamp, and then do groupBy and aggregate?

Comment: Another thing, I'm getting following error AnalysisException: u'No handler for Hive udf class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDAFCollectList because: Only primitive type arguments are accepted but array<double> was passed as parameter 1..;', do you have an idea why and how to fix it? When I'm only one column name into collect_list, so without array(), it works fine?

Comment: what spark version are you running, did you import the `array` function? are `a` ,`b` and `c` numeric columns?

Comment: Spark 1.6.2 and yes, I've imported the function and the columns have DoubleType?

Comment: Seems good now, thank you. Can you just explain the role of rank here? Is it just because we need some function so we could sort by partition? Seems that you're not using this column at all, in 2.0 version you're including it and then excluding while unfolding the list of lists, while for 1.6 you're not even including it? Why is that?

Comment: Because when you call collect list per column, the data will already be ordered because of the previously defined rank var, which is not the case when you use array inside collect_list() w/o the rank col in there. You can check the output without the window function to understand the difference.